# how to update database by sqlite file downloaded from internet at runtime?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, dbflow

I have sqlite file in assets and dbflow read it correctly but at runtime I sometimes need to download
a new updated sqlite file from internet and place it in certain folder in sdcard
so how to update dbflow database by this sqlite file in sdcard
to remove data of all tables
and add the new data from the file at sdcard to them ?

Comment: Simply copy the new database in place of the old one, by maintaining the same location. And restart your app. Your app will now use the new database.

Answer (score 0):

Try the BElow Code. This is a backup I had imported from Application for Restoring Data after Uninstall. Try the code. Hope it Works

**NB : PROVIDE READ AND WRITE PERMISSION ON RUNTIME AND IN MANIFEST TOO**

```
private void importDB() {
    try {
        File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        if (sd.canWrite()) {
            String currentDBPath = DOWNLOADEDDATAPATH; //SOURCE
            String backupDBPath = "data/" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/FILENAME";  //Destination


            File backupDB = new File(sd, currentDBPath);  //SOURCE
            File currentDB = new File(data, backupDBPath);  //Destination

            FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(backupDB).getChannel();  //SOURCE
            FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(currentDB).getChannel(); //Destination
            dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
            src.close();
            dst.close();


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("test", e.toString());
    }
}
```